# Interoperablility between .NET AND C

Tags: wcf

If I have a WebService (ICalculator as a service contract) written in wcf, can i access the service through a  client in C?

Comment: The "beauty" of a web service is that it's all just HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I.e. using [WWSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also I'd recommend C++ rather than pure C...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  C is the foundation of C++ and they together are the foundation of .NET.  If you can write it in C#, you can also write it in C.  (It may be more difficult, since the libraries to make it easy may not be there already.)

Comment: C++ and runtime environments like .NET and Java have very little (if anything) to do with each other. Language elements are common, yes, but that has nothing to do with whether or not "If you can write it in X, you can write it in Y." That's simply because they are Turing-complete languages.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: If you read up on the development of .NET, you'll notice that the first versions were written in C and C++ (with a dash of assembly for performance).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you will need to do a fair amount of work to call a webservice in c though.  Its not nearly as easy as doing it in C#, or  java, etc.